# SELECT OTHER TABLE

Tags: mysql

I have a little bit issue about MYSQL query

So I have table named "Diagnose" and "Diagnose Master"
in "Diagnose" there is an related field & record

idd   |   idmed   |   idf1   |   idf2   |   idf3

1     |      20       |    5     |     8     |     9

2     |      21       |    3     |     -      |    11

3     |      22       |    7     |     1     |     -

4     |      23       |    1     |      -     |     -

5     |      24       |    6     |      2    |     8

...

in "Diagnose Master"

iddm  |  code  |  name

1        |   A.1    |   ABC

2        |   A.2    |   ABCD

3        |   B.3    |  ABCDE

4        |   B.4    |  ABCDEF

5        |   C.5    | ABCDEFG

...

I need to select diagnose table with idf1, idf2, idf3 field replace by field name from diagnose master so the output will be

idd | idmed |        idf1      |         idf2       | idf3

1    |    20    | ABCDEFG | ABCDEFGH | ABCDEFGHIJ

2    |    21    |   ABCDE    |          -           | ABC

...

How to query that?

Thank You

Comment: You should really show some efforts of your SQL, and then ask for any suggestions

Comment: You need to look at `join` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to join DiagnoseMaster three times to the same table on three different columns, using three different aliases. Try something like this:

```
SELECT d.idd, d.idmed, dm1.name idf1, dm2.name idf2, dm3.name idf3 
    FROM Diagnose d
    JOIN DiagnoseMaster dm1 on dm1.idd = d.idf1
    JOIN DiagnoseMaster dm2 on dm2.idd = d.idf2
    JOIN DiagnoseMaster dm3 on dm3.idd = d.idf3
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Based on your query, null data will not be show, I need all record including null or sign "-"

Comment: use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN then.